# Creating complex list structure from data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm looking to create a list of lists from a data frame in R.

my data frame looks something like this:

```
  Name    Age
1 John    30
2 Dan     40
3 Charlie 20
...(few thousand rows)...
```

and I am trying to produce a list such that the keys for the list are the names in the data frame, and each key/name points to a list like `list(age=30)`

In the end, I'm looking for something like

```
 > str(list(John=list(age=30),Dan=list(age=40),Charlie=list(age=20),...))
 List of 3
  $ John   :List of 1
   ..$ age: num 30
  $ Dan    :List of 1
   ..$ age: num 40
  $ Charlie:List of 1
   ..$ age: num 20
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
z        <- lapply(df$Age,function(x)list(age=as.numeric(x)))
names(z) <- df$Name
str(z)
# List of 3
#  $ John   :List of 1
#   ..$ age: num 30
#  $ Dan    :List of 1
#   ..$ age: num 40
#  $ Charlie:List of 1
#   ..$ age: num 20
```

Comment: I really appreciate the versatility of this approach, although the other answer works particularly well if columns and keys are the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could combine `split`, `lapply` and `as.list`:

```
lapply(split(df, df$Name), function(x)as.list(x[-1]))
#$Charlie
#$Charlie$Age
#[1] 20

#$Dan
#$Dan$Age
#[1] 40

#$John
#$John$Age
#[1] 30
```

Comment: +1 because this approach works exactly in the conditions I set above.